# UIView disappears on keyboard pop on in swift5 and show Connection to daemon was invalidated

Tags: ios, uiview, swift5

in my uiview i have Text Field and Send button it is a chat app and when that view slide up its there but when type something it shows warning "**Connection to daemon was invalidated"**
for code to slideup keyboard i am using bindtokeyboard() function which works everywhere else perfectly.

```
func bindToKeyboard(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }
    @objc func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: NSNotification){
        let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
        let curve = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
        let beginingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let endFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let deltaY = endFrame.origin.y - beginingFrame.origin.y
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
            self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
        }, completion: nil)
        
    }
}
```

but when i bind it to UIView its not working.[its work till i type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esF0s.jpg)
[but when i type uiview disappears and that warning came on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTSXJ.jpg)